# Saving as csv output of applyin a "main" function in python

Tags: python, csv

I've been applying a main function in Python, by saying:

```
def main():
    "some code here"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I get a result like this:

```
[['This is my car not yours'], ['He answered me sorry'], ['no problem'], ['\nYou are crazy'], ['All cars are the same'], etc...]
```

I Want to save the result in a txt and csv file to manipulate it later preserving the same structure: squared parentheses, words, commas, etc.  How can I do that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use the csv module of python https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html 
it can transform the list into csv

Comment: and to print it directly as "python", use pretty print (pprint) https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html
another possiblity is python urscript.py > data.txt which is the shell ur using, redirecting standard output to a file

Comment: I don't understand what the `main()` function has to do with csv to be honest...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you wanted:

```
def main():
    return [['This is my car not yours'], ['He answered me sorry'], ['no problem'], ['\nYou are crazy'], ['All cars are the same']]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        a = ('').join(str(main()))
        f.write(a)
```

Comment: Thanks Boris, however, txt file is empty after apply your code. How to improve it?

Comment: I just edited my answer. You should change your `print` statement into `return`. Because I don't know your code inside main() this is my best guess.